# How to restart/delete an instance of mongod?

Tags: mongodb

This has been covered in other SO posts, but unfortunately those solutions are not working.

How does one restart/delete a mongod instance?

Entering

```
$ mongod
```

I get the following error:

```
2016-01-24T09:49:19.557-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=43675 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=NAME-MacBook-Pro.local
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.8
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 83d8cc25e00e42856924d84e220fbe4a839e605d
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin NAME-MacBook-Pro.local 15.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I explicitly gave myself permissions with

```
sudo chown -R <USERNAME> /data/db
```

This didn't work.

I tried to remove the directory entirely

```
sudo rm -rf /data/db
```

and recreate it

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work.

I thought the solution would be to remove the file `/data/db/mongod.lock` but it doesn't exist:

```
rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```

Anything else I should try?

EDIT: After running with the different port using `mongod --port 12345`, when I use `use admin` and then `db.shutdownServer()`, I get the following error:

```
2016-01-24T10:32:25.039-0500 I NETWORK  trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2016-01-24T10:32:25.039-0500 I NETWORK  reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) ok
2016-01-24T10:32:25.040-0500 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
```

EDIT 2:

Restarting the machine does nothing. I've tried to access the default port with `mongod --port 27017`, and then

```
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer()
```

I get the output:

```
2016-01-25T12:05:32.163-0500 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
2016-01-25T12:05:32.166-0500 I NETWORK  trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2016-01-25T12:05:32.166-0500 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-01-25T12:05:32.166-0500 I NETWORK  reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the log it say:

```
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-01-24T09:49:19.558-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
```

It means that the port is already in use either by another process or another mongo instance.

You should use another port for this instance.

[Refer to this link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-processes)